# Run a PHP script on an external server with feedback (via AJAX) only returns Error 405

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My problem is this: I have a HTML form for sending an EMail. And I have a PHP file to process said Form and send the EMail. The problem is, they are not on the same server (I have access to the PHP file, though). I have Bootstrap and JQuery on my page.

My form looks like this: (simplified)

```
<div id='form-messages'></div>
<form id='ajax-contact'>
several text fields, each one with name and id
<button type="submit" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

It's a simple form and it works. The problem is how I send the data to the PHP script. These script tags are at the end of the `<body>` tag:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  

$('#ajax-contact').on('click', function () {
              // Get the form.
              var form = $("#ajax-contact");

              // Get the messages div.
              var formMessages = $("#form-messages");

              // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
              $(form).submit(function(event) {
                // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
                event.preventDefault();

                // Serialize the form data
              var formData = $(form).serialize();
                });

              $.getJSON("my_path_to_the_php_script.php", function(formData){

              });
});
});

</script>
```

I was told to use getJSON to work around the fact that the PHP script doesn't lie on the same server as the HTML. AFAIK .getJSON sends a JSONP-string to the PHP file. What I want to check for is simply if the PHP-script has failed or not and display an error message above the form.

The reason I try to use .getJSON is because I already tried this:

```
 $.ajax({
                url:'my_path_to_the_php_script.php',
                type:'post',
                data: formData,
                jsonp: 'jsonp',
                dataType: 'jsonp', // use JSONP
                success: function(data){
                      // Display OK message
                      $(formMessages).html(<div class="alert alert-success">
                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">X</a>
                        Success!
                      </div>)

                      // Clear the form.
                      $(formMessages).each(function(){
                      this.reset();
                      });
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                $(formMessages).html(<div class="alert alert-danger">
                  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">X</a>
                  Warning Message!
                </div>)
                }

    });
```

Both methods don't work. All I want to do is to check if the script has failed or not. The $.getJSON() way doesn't work, it stays on the same page (as I expect), but the server returns an Error 405 page (Method not allowed). I don't have access to the header files of the PHP installation of that server. The $.ajax(dataType: 'jsonp') way doesn't work, returns Error 405.

Thanks for reading, please help.

Comment: There is no need for `$(form)` if `form` already stores a jQuery object (eg. `$('#ajax-contact')`), just use `form.submit();`. Also, take the habit of prepending your variable name with `$` if they store a jQuery object (ie. `$form`).

Comment: if it is on a different server you need to have the full url in the `url` value for the ajax function

Comment: Thanks. I'll rewrite this.

Comment: form submit handler shouldn't be inside a click handler

Comment: Also , `jsonp` doesn't support `POST` which is likely why you get 405

Comment: @samrap the url looks like this: "https://domainname/special_folder/other_folder/PHP2Mail.php" I hope nothing is wrong with that, it should point to the script.

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, doesn't work either, I just changed it and tried - still getting Error 405, even with type:'get',

Comment: if it's cross domain, which is what jsonp is used for, you need full protocol in url. If it's not cross domain, you wouldn't use jsonp